# Dataframe - Organising data and plotting columns on the x axis

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have  columns: "Country", "City", "Number of cars", "T0", "T1", "T2", "T5", "T10".

I want to plot a graph for each country where it shows me "T0", "T1", "T2", "T5", "T10" and different line for each "City".

Then I want a text that uses the "Number of cars" of each "City".

I would like this using dataframe.

I have tried setting "Country" and "City" set_index.
I have tried using plt.text(x,y, df.iloc[2]) in a loop but it prints out everything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding a small sample of your dataframe.